# Slightly different FFT results from Matlab fft and Scipy fft

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy, fft, precision

I've been making a routine which measures the phase difference between two spectra using NumPy/Scipy.

I already had the routine written in Matlab, so I basically re-implemented the function and the corresponding unit test using NumPy. However, I found that the unit test fails because `scipy.fftpack.fft` is introducing some small numerical errors:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack.fft
x = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0])
X = scipy.fftpack.fft(x)
```

In this case, since the time-domain signal is symmetric, the expected output is

```
[16.0000   -6.8284         0   -1.1716         0   -1.1716         0   -6.8284]
```

as shown in the following Matlab code:

```
>> x = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0];
>> X = fft(x)

X =

   16.0000   -6.8284         0   -1.1716         0   -1.1716         0   -6.8284
```

The result should not contain *any* imaginary components, based on DSP theory. However, the scipy result is as follows:

```
array([ 16.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,  -6.82842712 -2.22044605e-16j,
         0.00000000 -0.00000000e+00j,  -1.17157288 -2.22044605e-16j,
         0.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,  -1.17157288 +2.22044605e-16j,
         0.00000000 +0.00000000e+00j,  -6.82842712 +2.22044605e-16j])
```

Why does `scipy.fftpack.fft` introduce small imaginary components? I really want to avoid this issue. Could anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: You should always be prepared to expect a certain level of numerical error when dealing with finite-precision calculations.  In this case, it's 16 orders of magnitude below the signal level, so pretty reasonable.

Comment: I understand, but from the DSP theory, in this case, the FFT result should be real. Then does it mean that Scipy FFT library is worse than Matlab FFT library? With the Matlab library, the FFT result is real and doesn't contain any complex numbers.

Answer (score 5):

For one thing, [`scipy.fftpack.fft`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.fft.html#scipy.fftpack.fft) is *guaranteed* to always return a complex result, whereas the result of MATLAB's `fft` function is sometimes real and sometimes complex, depending on whether there is a non-zero imaginary component. However, that doesn't explain why the result of `scipy.fftpack.fft` actually contains non-zero imaginary components, whereas the result of MATLAB's `fft` function does not.

I suspect that the underlying reason for the difference has to do with the fact that MATLAB's `fft` function is apparently [based](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html#moreabout) on [FFTW](http://www.fftw.org/), whereas scipy and numpy use [FFTPACK](http://www.netlib.org/fftpack/) due to licensing restrictions.

[`pyfftw`](http://hgomersall.github.io/pyFFTW/), however, does provide Python bindings to FFTW. If we compare the imaginary components of the results for FFTPACK and FFTW:

```
from pyfftw.interfaces import scipy_fftpack as fftw

Fx1 = fftpack.fft(x)
print(Fx1.imag)
# [  0.00000000e+00  -2.22044605e-16  -0.00000000e+00  -2.22044605e-16
#    0.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16   0.00000000e+00   2.22044605e-16]
print(Fx1.imag == 0)
# [ True False  True False  True False  True False]

Fx2 = fftw.fft(x)
print(Fx2.imag)
# [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
print(Fx2.imag == 0)
# [ True  True  True  True  True  True  True  True]
```

we see that the imaginary component of the FFTW result compares *exactly* equal to zero, whereas FFTPACK has a tiny amount of floating-point rounding error.

Beyond that, I have no idea why FFTW's implementation suffers less from rounding error than FFTPACK, but in any case it's important to note that these rounding errors are small enough that they normally don't cause problems (you know you shouldn't be testing for exact equality between float values, right?).

Usually you would simply take the real component of the result, e.g.:

```
scipy.fftpack.fft(x).real
```

If these errors *are* a problem then you could switch to using `pyfftw` instead of numpy/scipy, but if your code is *that* sensitive to rounding error then it probably means you're doing something wrong anyway.

Comment: You probably understand this, but just to be clear: `scipy.fftpack.rfft` returns a "non-complex result", but only because it represents the complex components as distinct elements of a real array.  `scipy.fftpack.rfft([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])` still gives a result containing nonzero (but tiny) imaginary components.

Comment: Generally when dealing with floating point numbers, you should use an error marging for the tests. About a few granularity steps should suffice. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Floating_Point/Epsilon